# Desktop app & Youtube search API auth, C++

Tags: authentication, oauth, youtube, google-api

I'm writing a toy desktop application in C++. It will need to search YouTube for a song. Currently the app calls [googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search) with `key` parameter. This is nice, easy to write but causes a auth problem.

I can't distribute the key along with the app, because then it is vulnerable to quota theft and other things(as a workaround, I currently require to generate your own API keys and put them in your config - it's inconvenient and smells like a dirty hack). Google allows to restrict keys, but only based on: IP, HTTP referrers, specific Android app, specific iOS app. None of these apply. So, I would have to store that data elsewhere or use some other method of auth. The first would require some kind of a server that runs 24/7 somewhere with its own quota limiting which has even more problems and is absurd - there has to be a proper way. When I try to use Google Developer Console's credential wizard, after asking a few things about my app it only tells me that I should use an API key.

What I would like:

- App should connect directly to Google - they should be able to regulate quota just like they do with normal searches from a browser.
- No storing API keys in app code. This is a really simple and tempting solution, but no.
- No need to log in. YouTube can be searched even without and account, so it should be possible to do that through API.
- No using a browser with something like Selenium. This stuff is slow, painful to write and maintain.

I feel like I'm really unfamiliar with this stuff and there is an obvious solution somewhere; after all, you can do YouTube searches at any time, whenever you want - through a browser. How to do this from a desktop app?

Comment: In addition to Desktop applications (without browser), the problem is the same for Android/IOS applications : see [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/153511/why-youtube-or-any-other-google-services-use-account-binded-authorization-key-p)

Comment: Three answers there say: 1) something about premium plan which wouldn't even solve the problem, 2) it's impossible, 3) use middleware. A bit discouraging, but huge thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a headless browser like PhantomJS, Selenium webdriver or Headless Chromium etc. You can render the web search results in the headless mode and then can extract the results from there like normal browsers. I personally haven't used them with C++ but I'm pretty sure these have C++ bindings as well.

Comment: I already knew about that(and mentioned it the question), but thanks for mentioning PhantomJS and Headless Chromium aside from Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER**: I don't know whether this qualifies as a *legal* use of Google's services, please research before using .

You can use another provider like [www.noembed.com](https://noembed.com/) to do the dirty work (scraping i guess)for you.
A sample query request would look like

`http://noembed.com/embed?url=http%3A//www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DbDOYN-6gdRE&callback=my_embed_function`

This example is directly taken from their home page (linked above).

I know this does not look clean (i don't like to do it this way), but it is something for you to consider

Comment: Well, that's something I didn't think of. The bad point is that you have to sacrifice your privacy, but is seems there is not really a better way.